# Debian with 2 ethernet as VPN relay (route all traffic from eth0 to eth1 VPN)

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, ip, nat

## Background

I got 2 Debian VMs, first one is pptp/wireguard server on WAN `10.10.0.1` and second one's eth0 `192.168.100.1`, eth1 `172.16.100.1`.

> Note: WAN IPs written in private ranges Intentionally

## Problem

I want second VM's eth1 `172.16.100.1` to connect to first VM `10.10.0.1` as VPN client, then run a VPN server on eth0 `192.168.100.1` which routes all traffic through eth1 to the first VM.
Basically, then I can connect to second VM's eth0 then and use first VM's VPN.
**Client -->  VM2-eth0 --> VM2-eth1 --> VM1-eth0**

> Please provide details on any required packages (if any) along with iptables rules and other commands

Comment: Did you set up both VPNs already so you just need help with routing?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, just routing rules plz